# extract information from tables in truetype font file

Tags: pdf, encoding, fonts, truetype

While parsing a pdf file, my parser encounter a Tf operator with the value of the SubType entry in the font dictionary set to TrueType. The Encoding entry is not present, the symblic flag is set.

My question is : how do I suppose to map the character codes to characters with no encoding ?

The [PDF reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) section 5.5.5 Character Encoding states that TrueType font has internal data represented in tables in the font files. It seems that those tables would help me map the character codes. Am I getting it right ? How can I extract those information from the font file ?

The font file extracted from the PDF gave something like :
[image: the font file viewed in a hex editor]

I read Apple's documentation [The True Type Font File](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6.html#Directory) but still don't get how can I extract those informations from those tables.

Any help, links or reading suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check whatever is extracting the font data from the PDF. That is not a valid TrueType (OpenType) font file. It looks like there's some extra information before the actual start of the file, at byte 32 in your screen capture. Then the data format in the Apple spec (and OpenType spec pointed out elsewhere) will make more sense.

Comment: @djangodude : you mean my font file starts at byte 32 ? How do you see that ?

Comment: I know that from having seen quite a few TrueType fonts in my time, and from some of the pixels :-) If you started interpreting the font starting at byte 32 of the dump you show above, it should parse out correctly according to the Apple specification.

Answer (score 1):

Symblic flag means that encoding is set to [0..255] range. Every character code must be in the this range. Font presents glyphs only for these codes.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/) is a great set of resources regarding TrueType and OpenType font formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use freetype library function FT_Get_Char_Index for going from a character code to a glyph index. See [FT_Get_Char_Index](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Get_Char_Index)

You'll have to dump the truetype font to file and load it with freetype to get an FT_Face first.